# What is wrong with this induction proof? I am confused on how this is wrong other than the base case being wrong.

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

**P(*n*):** $n=2n$ for all integers $n >= 0$

**Base Case:** *n* = 0

- **Verify Base Case:**

  P(0): 0 = 2(0) which is true
- **Induction Step:**

  Assume that P(*n*) is true. Then multiply both sides of the quantity by $(n+1)/n$ which gives us $n+1=2(n+1)$ = $P(n+1)$

I am not sure what exactly makes this proof wrong despite me knowing it is false.

Comment: to get from P($0$) to P($1$) you would multiply by $1/0$, but division by $0$ is not allowed

Comment: With problems like this, it's always good to write out the first inductive step completely.  Try to use this argument to show $P(1)$, i.e. try to show that $1=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have divided by $n$ in your induction step where you have multiplied by $(n+1)/n$

Note that you may not divide by $n=0$ but your initial step was involving $n=0$

Thus your argument fails at $$P(0)\implies P(1)$$

Answer (score 4):

What makes the proof wrong is that, when $n=0$, you cannot multiply by $(n+1)/n$,

because that would involve dividing by $0$, so it is not allowed.

For a different kind of induction fallacy, see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color).

Answer (score 1):

When applying the inductive step for the first time with $n=0$, you are instructed to multiply by $\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{1}{0}$. Clearly, this is not a well defined number and, hence, not a well-defined step.